# how to disable auto-capitalization of email type on iOS devices

Tags: nativescript

I'd like to disable auto-capitalization of email type on iOS devices. this is my field:

```
<TextField hint="Email" class="input input-border" keyboardType="email"></TextField>
```

First character will be capitalized when I fill it and i want to prevent auto-capitalization.

any idea?

Answer (score 5):

i found it. just adding `autocapitalizationType` property to it. finally it will be like this:

```
<TextField autocapitalizationType="none" autocorrect="false" hint="Email" class="input input-border" keyboardType="email"></TextField>
```